# How to be sure that public key belongs to private key (RSA) without modulus check?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, match, rsa

I'm generating RSA key pairs using `Node.js` and they are both stored in database (private keys are AES-encrypted).

I want to check if the decrypted private key matches the public key, to make sure that the public key has not been replaced/tampered while at rest.

I found no way to get the keys modulus with the `Node.js` API.

If I simply encrypt a random message and get the original message when decrypting, is it ok ?

I just want to know if this is safe, i don't really care if it's slow or not optimal.

Is there any way i can do it without any external libraries ?

I don't really want to directly use `openssl` CLI from node either.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Store the public key also? That is usually a small number.

Comment: Both of the public and private keys are stored.

Comment: Do you store the `p` and `q` also? If so, use `e x d = 1 \mod \phi(n)`  else encrypt and decrypt some test messages.

Comment: the keys are stored in PEM format. i don't store indivudual fields. that's my main problem. cause i can't get individual fields (for eg modulus) from node.js either.

Comment: Ok, great. The keys are intended for encryption/decryption, so i think i will stick to my first idea of encrypting/decrypting a random message to check if everything went smooth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we create a signature over some known message and verify that (even over an empty octet string), but encryption / decryption would work as well. Probably best to make sure you use the operation that the key was *originally intended for* Do make sure you don't sign or encrypt a message that could be used by an adversary and/or don't leak the result.

It is impossible that a different private key can be used that isn't *functionality equivalent*. There may still be differences though, e.g. a private key can contain the private exponent for direct exponentiation with that private exponent (plain RSA), or it can contain the key generation parameters used for the Chinese Remainder Theorem. In that case it doesn't require the private exponent.